# .htaccess not rewriting properly for m3u8 playlist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to generate a m3u8 playlist with a php script... It works but many applications don't accept the php extension, so I thought of using the htacces... with no luck

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\.+).m3u8$ $1.m3u8.php [NC,L]
```

this does not work (gives a file not found when calling list.m3u8). Permission is 755. Never learned how .htaccess works so I'm not sure what's not working.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.m3u8$ $1.m3u8.php [NC,L]
```

OR to redirect URL itself in browser try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.m3u8$ /$1.m3u8.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I think you missed escaping dot before `m3u8` in rule pattern

Comment: @anubhava, yeah that is needed to make it be treated as literal character, thank you for letting know sir I have changed now,cheers.

Comment: @gotch4, could you please clear cache of your browser OR try in incognito mode or your chrome browser, both worked fine for me. Also if after clearing is not working you could try to restart apache service + clear cache of browser and try once please, kindly do let me know how it goes.

Comment: I did try that but still does not work. I'm starting to think my provider doesn't support it properly

Comment: @gotch4, are there any other rules present in .htaccess file too?

Comment: @gotch4, strange these both have worked fine for me.

Comment: as I mentioned, I am using a low cost hosting provider, so they may restrict some functionality

Comment: @gotch4, so any error are you getting on browser or in logs? Kindly do let me know.

Comment: @gotch4 If `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled on the server then this will simply _do nothing_ (no error). If `.htaccess` overrides are enabled, but mod_rewrite is not enabled/loaded then you'll get an error (unless you are on a LiteSpeed server, in which case it will likely just silently fail.) Write some "nonsense" in the `.htaccess` file - do you get an error? If no error then `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled (or you are on a LiteSpeed server).